# Adding ui.bootstrap dependency with bower

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bower

I m trying to add ui.bootstrap dependency to my angular project (I m using yeoman, bower).
I did this :

1. yo angular
2. bower install angular-ui
3. I then added to my index.html file :  and
4. grunt serve

Then I added the ui.bootstrap dependency to my app.js:

```
angular.module('angularuiprojectApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

When I m trying to access to my index.html on Chrome I m getting this error :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   angularuiprojectApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to: Error: [$injector:nomod]
>   Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either ......1)

I don't know where I m wrong, if someone can help me on this...
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you added the correct file to `index.html`? Has it perhaps been replaced by ill-configured `bower-install`? Do you get any `404` errors in the browser?

Answer (score 59):

You are installing a wrong package from bower. The correct one to install is `bower install angular-bootstrap` as described here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#installation

**Edit**:

As of February 2015, a Bower version of the library exists at https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.

<strike>Unfortunately, it presently only contains AngularUI Bootstrap 0.12.0 which, as far as I can tell, isn't fully compatible with Angular >= 1.3. It looks like the maintainers intend AngularUI Bootstrap >= 0.13.0 to be compatible with Angular 1.3, <>but that version of the library seems not to have made its way to the Bower-compatible repo yet.</strike>
No longer an issue, AngularUI Bootstrap 0.13.0 version is now provided and supported.

Comment: Using install angular-bootstrap didnt work either, I had to update manually bower.json in order to add the dependency. After that, it worked.

Comment: next time you can save as you install with -S or --save

Comment: @user1260928 what exactly did you? I'm hitting the same issue.

Comment: @Sebastialonso if you still looking for solution check the following out https://www.versioneye.com/javascript/angular-ui:angular-ui-bootstrap-bower/0.11.0

Answer (score 3):

install the bower version that depends on the angular version that your project uses.

I first installed;

```
bower install angular-ui-bootstrap-bower#0.13.4
```

Then I added below to bower.json

```
"angular-ui-bootstrap-bower": "0.13.4"
```

Comment: You can execute "bower install angular-ui-bootstrap-bower#0.13.4 --save"  <-- add the "--save". That will add the dependency to your bower.json for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
bower install angular-ui-bootstrap --save
```

This also works.

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605162/inject-provider-into-directive-not-working) if you have any issue with the version installed by bower. There seems to be some version issues with ui-boostrap quoting the answer