# inject provider into directive not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use [angular-bootstrap-lightbox](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox#basic-example) , and i need to inject Lightbox
provider into directive like so

```
controller: ['Lightbox' , function ($scope, $rootScope, $filter, FileUploader,Lightbox) {
```

but this is lead to the following error :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- Lightbox <- Lightbox
```

any body can help to resolve this , Thanks in advance .

Comment: can you provide your module declaration? There also should be injected the dependency.

Comment: sure i put it : ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils','xeditable','ngImgCrop','angularFileUpload','envConfig','angulartics','angulartics.google.analytics','bootstrapLightbox'];

Comment: what about script list that is imported into your page?do you have there all these libs? And second question - do you see any errors in console?

Comment: yes i use all this libs , 
no errors in console except the provided above

Comment: Hm, Can you please create a plunkr to reproduce the issue you have?

Comment: Are you including angular bootstrap, so that the $uibModal service is defined? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/top
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started

Comment: @HasanDaghash were you able to figure this out?  Having the same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Version issue with ui-boostrap.  Need to upgrade ui-bootstrap to be 0.14x or above.  See this [github issue](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/issues/42) as well

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to upgrade `angular-bootstrap` past `0.12.0`, make sure that your `angular-dialog-service` is at version `5.2.6` exactly (no `~`s or `^`s preceding it!).  Downgrading `angular-dialog-service` solved this issue for us.

Comment: Excellent point! It has to do with the dependence on bootstrap. Using ~5.2.6 for instance resolved me to bootstrap 3.0.5 which caused the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this version, it will clear the error:

```
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this cdn script tag in the index of your angular app

```
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.0.js"></script>
```