# Why isn't angular bootstrap being injected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bower

**How do I correctly inject angular bootstrap into an angularjs app?**

When I manually include remote versions of the libraries with the following code in `index.html`, **angular bootstrap works**:

```
<!-- start manual dependencies for testing purposes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.0" data-require="angularjs@1.5.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<link data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.13.1" data-semver="0.13.1" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.13.1" data-semver="0.13.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- end manual dependencies for testing purposes -->
```

However, **the app stops compiling** (meaning that JavaScript does not work at all and only html is served to the browser) **when I try to have the dependencies managed automatically**.

I read [this other posting on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178753/adding-ui-bootstrap-dependency-with-bower) and tried its suggestions as follows, so this is not a duplicate posting:

```
[user@localhost client]$ bower install angular-bootstrap
bower cached        git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#1.2.5
bower validate      1.2.5 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#*
[user@localhost client]$
```

Bower then generates the following list of includes in `index.html`, which replace the manual includes shown above:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And `bower.json` includes the following:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^1.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "clientApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Since the app compiles and runs JavaScript properly when the http includes at top are used, you really do not need to know how I am injecting `ui.bootstrap` into the app modules, but I am including as follows for thoroughness:

```
angular
  .module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'ngTouch', 
      'auth', 'home', 'secure', 'public1', 'navigation',
      'ui.bootstrap' ])
```

**What specific changes need to be made to the above in order to successfully inject angular bootstrap into the app from the local bower folders?**

Comment: Are all files listed in the same order as before, including relative to your application code?  Also, is your browser able to find your bower directory?

Comment: @tyler  The browser is certainly able to find the bower directory because the angular app works with the automated build until i try to add angular-bootstrap.  The orders are exactly as shown in the OP.  Is there any addition file that I should post?

Comment: @estus This app does not use wiredep.  The setup includes node.js, yeoman, Grunt, and bower.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're using to automate the file paths, but it's missing the `angular-bootstrap` main js file.  You'll need it **and** the templates (which you're already including) like so:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I would like to test this without disabling Bower's auto-generation of dependencies into `index.html`.  `bower.json` seems to be the file that defines what gets generated.  I posted it above.  What do I add to `bower.json` in order to generate the includes that you suggest?  And is this something I should set manually in `bower.json`, or in a `bower install ...` command, or somewhere else like `GruntFile.js`?

Comment: Should be in your gruntfile -- this is not a bower issue.  Grunt is a build tool, so it's likely the one moving things around. (side note: I'd recommend gulp instead, personally)

Comment: Try searching your various config files for `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` wherever you see that is a good candidate for where you'd need to add the `ui-bootstrap.js` file into the build process.